# What am I missing in this avoidance of the diamond problem?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, initializer-list

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my inheritance structure:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    protected:
    int x;
    public:
    A() : x(5) { }
    A(int a) : x(a) { }
    int get() { return x; }
    void set(int i) { x = i; return *this; }
};

class B : virtual public A {
    protected:
    int x;
    public:
    B() : x(10), A(6) { }
    B(int b) : x(b), A(6) { }
    int get() { return x; }
    void set(int i) { x = i; return *this; }
};

class C : virtual public A {
    protected:
    int x;
    public:
    C() : x(20), A(7) { }
    C(int c) : x(c), A(7) { }
    int get() { return x; }
    void set(int i) { x = i; return *this; }
};

class D : public B, public C {
    protected:
    int x;
    public:
    D() : x(35), B(11), C(21) { }
    int get() { return x; }
    void set(int i) { x = i; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    std::cout << d.B::A::get() << "\n";
    std::cout << d.C::A::get() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, my classes form a diamond. I know that virtual inheritance is required to disambiguate the base class, but I don't think my constructors are correct because my intention is to get this as output:

```
6
7
```

But instead, I get this:

```
5
5
```

Where is my error? Is it in the initializer lists, or the calls, or something else?

Comment: You've used virtual inheritance so only have one instance of `A`. Calling all your member variables the same thing is very confusing

Comment: Your expectation is wrong as your understanding is *fundamentally incorrect*. The virtual inheritance of `A` in your hierarchy cause `d.B::A` and `d.C::A` to refer to *exactly* the same `A`.   So, at the least, your code will print the same value twice (since `d.B::A::get()` and `d.C::A::get()` resolve to the same function named `get()` and so return the value of the same member).  There is also an impact on how virtual bases are initialised (but your code doesn't actually demonstrate that well).

Comment: Virtual inheritance is not required to "disambiguate the base class". Virtual inheritance is required when your **design** calls for a single sub-object of the base type. If your design calls for multiple sub-objects of the base type (not common, but not unreasonable) then virtual inheritance is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with redefining the member variable x in classes B - C -D

I assume it will create 3 distinct x variables with the same name in your inheritance hierarchy -- when you want to access x through an object of class D the compiler could confuse which one which could cause unexpected results

I would define x only in class A and then access it using scope resolution operator (::)

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    protected:
    int x;
    public:
    A() : x(5) { }
    A(int a) : x(a) { }
    int get() { return x; }
    void set(int i) { x = i; }
};

class B : virtual public A {
    public:
    B() : A(6) { }
    B(int b) : A(6) { }
};

class C : virtual public A {
    public:
    C() : A(7) { }
    C(int c) : A(7) { }
};

class D : public B, public C {
    public:
    D() : A(35), B(), C() { }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    std::cout << d.B::A::get() << "\n";
    std::cout << d.C::A::get() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This now prints the result 35 rather than the expected 6,7 so its not really answering the OP's question